# WebRTC in Express

Tags: node.js, express, webrtc

I have an HTML file that is identical to the example used on http://simplewebrtc.com/

But when I try to throw it into an express server, it doesn't work. Here's my code:

index.js

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

app.get('/home', function(req,res){
 res.sendfile(__dirname + '/public/home.html');
}); 

app.listen(4000)
console.log("App listening on port 4000");
```

home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//simplewebrtc.com/latest.js"></script> 
        <script>
          var webrtc = new SimpleWebRTC({
          // the id/element dom element that will hold "our" video
          localVideoEl: 'localVideo',
          // the id/element dom element that will hold remote videos
          remoteVideosEl: 'remotesVideos',
          // immediately ask for camera access
          autoRequestMedia: true
        });

          // we have to wait until it's ready
          webrtc.on('readyToCall', function () {
            // you can name it anything
            webrtc.joinRoom('your awesome room name');
          });
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <video height="300" id="localVideo"></video>
        <div id="remotesVideos"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It needs to communicate with something like - ``https://github.com/andyet/signalmaster``, not a simple express applicatio, I think.

Comment: Really? Then why does running the HTML file on a simple apache server work?

Comment: I have not found any socket specific code in your express application. When WebRTC will work, they need implementation from Server also. By definition, ``Apache Web Server`` and ``node.js`` web server are not same.

Comment: @PiyasDe I think the problem here is CORS, in `webrtc` the server is nearly irrelevent...

Comment: server is needed for signalling, and sometimes under special cirumstances a TURN/STUN is required.

Answer (score 0):

try changing the url of the sandbox signaling server as shown in http://simplewebrtc.com/notsosimple.html#sandbox-server

Running your server on a different port causes issues since the default url doesn't include a port for the signaling server so it will try to connect to signaling.simplewebrtc.com:4000 and nothing is answering there.